# UCWA APIs from a client application

Tags: java, azure, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I'm developing a java client that needs to access Skype for Business APIs and I followed this Microsoft doc step by step

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/developingucwaapplicationsforsfbonline

My difficult is to understand how to resgister an application on Azure.

When the manual says:

Click the Active Directory node in the left column and select the directory linked to your Skype for Business subscription.

what does exactly it means? It means that I need a Skype for business online subscription?

I have an Azure account with admin rights and I have a Tenant (with a specific domain name); I suppose I need to install skype for business on my Azure tenant in order to proceede with my client application registration.

I've just worked with Skype on premises but I don't know skype on Cloud.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out by following these steps:

1. I purchased an Office 365 license (Premium edition);
2. I created an Office 365 tenant (by using administrator rights) which is automatically registered on the Azure platform;
3. I configured a Skype for Business online instance and I created several user accounts for it;
4. I registered my client application java based on the tenant;
5. I applied the UCWA handshake and finally invoked Skype for Business web APIs.

I hope this brief explanation can be useful for developers to interact with Microsoft Office 365 APIs by using the UCWA handshake and the authentication token released by Azure.